# QGIS batch processing does not allow the output from an algorithm as the input to a subsequent algorithm

Tags: qgis, batch, qgis-modeler

Using QGIS 2.18.14, Windows 10, I need help with Batch Processing.  I have created this simple model with just two algorithms, a reproject followed by polygon centroids:

[image]

When I try to run this model as a batch process, I follow the [QGIS instructions for filling out the Parameter Table](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html).  The autofill dropdown for the first algorithm works correctly, allowing me to select the input layer.

However, there is a problem with the second algorithm's dropdown; just like the first algorithm it only includes the input layer as an option.  It does not allow me to select the output from first algorithm, which is necessary to complete the model.

[image]

How do I enable the parameter table to offer intermediate output as a selection option?  Without this ability, only one algorithm is possible in batch processing.

**EDIT:** For clarity, my problem is not with the model itself, but rather the batch processor: it does not provide the ability for an algorithm to accept, as input, the output of a previous algorithm.

inability of the batch processor to accept the output of an algorithm

Comment: Are you _sure_ the model does not run correctly? The parameters for the **Autofill settings** are only used to create filenames for the output, it should not affect the actual processing algorithms used. I ran a similar test model and the output shapefile was correctly processed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Joseph.  My OP may have been confusing, so I added an edit.  Here's a summary of the problem: When filling out the batch process page, the autofill dropdown does not display the output from a previous algorithm.  So, this works: INPUT -> ALGORITHM_1, but this does not work: INPUT -> ALGORITHM_1 -> ALGORITHM_2, because the output from ALGORITHM_1 is not available in the dropdown as input to ALGORITHM_2.  Whew, that's a mouthful, I hope I've clarified things.

Comment: @Joseph, in other words... how were you able to autofill the second algorithm?

Comment: Ahh apologies, I misunderstood. I thought the problem was with the actual model. No you are correct, the autofill selection does not seem to offer an option for the first output. You could consider posting a [feature request](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis) as I don't think it's currently possible.

Answer (score 2):

In my OP, I stated that *"...the batch processor ... does not provide the ability for an algorithm to accept, as input, the output of a previous algorithm."*

That statement is incorrect.  The batch processor **will** allow the output of one algorithm to be the input of a subsequent algorithm. Thus, multiple algorithms can be daisy-chained together, with the output of one acting as the input to the next.

I misunderstood the purpose of the Autofill settings.  The "Parameter to use" dropdown in the OP's second screenshot only includes the "Input layer" option, which led me to incorrectly believe that an algorithm could only accept the input layer as a data source.

Instead, the purpose of the "Parameter to use" is to provide a naming convention for the algorithm's output.  For each algorithm (displayed as columns in the OP's second image) click […] in the top row of its output column.  Navigate to the output layer’s desired directory.  In the “Save as” window, enter a string, which will act as a **prefix** to the input layer name.  In my example I used the string "Projected_", which is displayed under the circled number 1. If you look closely, you'll see that the output from that algorithm has the text string "Projected_" added as a prefix to each of the four input layer names.  Thus:

Input layer name ->   Algorithm 1 output name

QPF1029_12Z     ->    **Projected**_QPF1029_12Z

QPF1029_18Z    ->     **Projected**_QPF1029_18Z

QPF1030_00Z    ->     **Projected**_QPF1030_00Z

...

For the second algorithm (and this is where I was originally confused), repeat the same naming process as described above, but providing a **different prefix**.  Using my OP as an example, I could have prefixed the output of the second algorithm (confusingly displayed in the first output column under the red circled 2) with something like "Centroid_", with the following result:

Input layer name ->   Algorithm 1 output name ->   Algorithm 2 output name

QPF1029_12Z -> **Projected**_QPF1029_12Z -> **Centroid**_QPF1029_12Z

QPF1029_18Z -> **Projected**_QPF1029_18Z -> **Centroid**_QPF1029_18Z

QPF1030_00Z -> **Projected**_QPF1030_00Z -> **Centroid**_QPF1030_00Z

...

In summary, as this batch process cycles, each of the input layers will go through the two algorithms. Each algorithm's output is named according to the prefix provided in the "Parameter to use" dropdown.

[This QGIS tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/batch_processing.html) helped me understand how to connect multiple algorithms.
Thanks also to @Joseph for his insight.